# how to validate textbox to check if the value entered is english

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

i want to validate textbox to check if the value entered is english
and this is my validate class

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Vytru.Base;

namespace Vytru.Platform.Bridge.Configuration.Manager
{
     class MapDevice : IDataErrorInfo
     {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
        public string SipURI { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FQDN { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public SipServerTransportType _TransportType { get; set; }
        public PeerType _PeerType { get; set; }
        public string PeerURI { get; set; }


        #region Implementation of IDataErrorInfo

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;
                if (columnName.Equals("UserName"))
                {
                    // check for null or empty values 
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
                    {
                         result = "User Name cannot be null or empty";
                    }
                    else if (UserName.Length > 50)
                    {
                        result = "More than 50 characters";
                    }
                    else if (UserName.Length < 3)
                    {
                        result = "less than 3 characters";
                    }
                    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(UserName, @"\w+"))
                    {
                         result = "Entered User Name format is not valid ...only A-Z 0-9";
                    }

                }

                else if (columnName.Equals("AgentName"))
                {
                    // check for null or empty values 
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AgentName))
                    {
                         result = "Agent Name cannot be null or empty";
                    }
                    else if (AgentName.Length < 3)
                    {
                         result = "less than 3 characters";
                    }

                    else if (AgentName.Length > 50)
                    {
                         result = "More than 50 characters";
                    }

                    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(AgentName, @"\w+"))
                    {
                         result = "Entered AgentName format is not valid ... only A-Z 0-9";
                    }

                }

                else if (columnName.Equals("SipURI"))
                {
                    // check for null or empty values 
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SipURI))
                    {
                         result = "Sip URI cannot be null or empty";
                    }

                    else if (SipURI.Length < 3)
                    {
                         result = "less than 3 characters";
                    }

                    else if (SipURI.Length > 50)
                    {
                         result = "More than 50 characters";
                    }

                    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(SipURI, @"(s|S)+(i|I)+(p|P)+(:)+\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"))
                    {
                         result = "Entered SipURI format is not valid ... ";
                    }


                }

                if (columnName.Equals("Password"))
                {
                     // check for null or empty values 
                     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                     {
                          result = "Password cannot be null or empty";
                     }
                     else if (Password.Length > 50)
                     {
                          result = "More than 50 characters";
                     }
                     else if (Password.Length < 3)
                     {
                          result = "Less than 3 characters";
                     }

                     else if (!Regex.IsMatch(Password, @"\w+"))
                     {
                          result = "Entered Password is not valid ... only A-Z 0-9 ";
                     }


                }

                else if (columnName.Equals("FQDN"))
                {
                     // check for null or empty values 
                     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FQDN))
                     {
                          result = "FQDN cannot be null or empty";
                     }
                     else if (FQDN.Length > 50)
                     {
                          result = "More than 50 characters";
                     }
                     else if (FQDN.Length < 3)
                     {
                          result = "Less than 3 characters";
                     }
                     else if (!Regex.IsMatch(FQDN, @"\w+"))
                     {
                          result = "Entered FQDN format is not valid ... only A-Z 0-9";
                     }

                }

                else if (columnName.Equals("Domain"))
                {
                     // check for null or empty values 
                     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Domain))
                     {
                          result = "Domain cannot be null or empty";
                     }

                     else if (Domain.Length > 50)
                     {
                          result = "More than 50 characters";
                     }
                     else if (Domain.Length < 2)
                     {
                          result = "Less than 3 characters";
                     }

                     else if (!Regex.IsMatch(Domain, @"\w+"))
                     {
                          result = "Entered Domain format is not valid ...  ";
                     }


                }

                else if (columnName.Equals("PeerURI"))
                {
                     // check for null or empty values 
                     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PeerURI))
                     {
                          result = "PeerURI cannot be null or empty";
                     }

                     else if (PeerURI.Length > 50)
                     {
                          result = "More than 50 characters";
                     }
                     else if (PeerURI.Length < 3)
                     {
                          result = "Less than 3 characters";
                     }

                     else if (!Regex.IsMatch(PeerURI, @"\w+"))
                     {
                          result = "Entered PeerURI format is not valid ...";
                     }

                }

                return result;

            }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        #endregion



     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's feasible to validate that something is English. You would need to define what English is, and that's pretty much an impossible task.

Heuristically, you could do something like run the value through a spell-checker with an English dictionary, or do an "[auto-detect language](http://www.labnol.org/internet/identify-language-of-text/8441/)" call using e.g. the Google languages API, but this would certainly not be 100% reliable, especially with short fields (it's not clear what field you want to validate, but they all look like they would have short inputs).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this.

**The First:**
Downloading an XML (Or other format) English dictionary containing as many words as possible. Then creating in index file by hashing each word. Then hashing each word in your input and finally comparing it to your index file.

**The Second:**
You can find a CFG for the English language. Then get a lexical and syntactical analyzer that can parse your input according to the CFG, to see if the input is in fact, in the English language.

This isn't very easy to accomplish in my opinion. But if anyone else can think of an easier way, please share.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [index of coincidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence). It is fairly accurate when you evaluate enough text. Maybe in combination with a regex looking for certain characteristic combinations (eg `th') or use regex to look for articles (a, an & the).

A next step could be when you have another language that has about the same score, let's say German, to examen that more closely by looking for a Ringel-S for instance.

A last but maybe unwanted step would be to check the words against some kind of dictionary. Maybe you can use [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/) for instance to check if the words you look for return a result instead of a not found response. If you can fix to POST and GET to such a site you build in another check.

Again, you need to have some text. Not just a few words... I have a table somewhere defining a few languages. If you can't find it yourself, I can send you that if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution would be using regex. 
Here is what I used once:

```
if( Regex.IsMatch(Console.ReadLine(), "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") )
{ 
}
```